# Setting multiple cores option with cplex matlab toolbox function cplexmilp

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, cplex

I am using CPLEX for MATLAB toolbox wherein I formulate my MILP as a huge matrix and use the function cplexmilp to call the solver. Since the model I am solving is really huge, I intend to set the option of using multiple processors to speed up the solving of the MILP. I went through the manual but I could not find any specific solution for my case. I'd be grateful if anyone could help me find a  solution to this issue.

[CPLEX Toolbox Function](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.2.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX1182.html)

Thanks Everyone

Comment: Cplex has an option (or parameter) 'threads' for this.

Comment: I set this option to 7 and when I run the top command to see the CPU utilisation, it still shows 100% despite having around 12 cores. Correct me if I am wrong. When I set the threads to 7, must the CPU utilisation go beyond 100% (like 250 or 700 or whatever) ?

Comment: Set diagnostics to on and see if the Cplex log tells you something about using all cores. Note that pieces of the the MIP solve are not really parallel (especially in the beginning during and before the root solve). Once Cplex starts with the branch-and-bound it should start efficiently using all those cores.

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late but it works. Thanks a lot. Would there be a possibility to also do something similar to speed up the build of constraint matrix?

Comment: For large complex models I usually export the MATLAB  data, and then implement the model itself in AMPL or GAMS. This strategy works well for me.